# What's the cleanest way of counting the number of views on a post in a database?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm doing a little gallery of images and for each image I wanna tell the user how many times that images has been viewed. I.e. every time I `SELECT` an image in the database I wanna do a +1 on the 'views' column of that row in the db. But what would be the most efficient way of doing this?

It just doesn't seam 'clean' to do a `SELECT` to get the image and then an `UPDATE` just to do +1 for the view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making a **helper** that just updates the image id views - takes the id as a parameter. In the long run, this will prove much easier to maintain. If you're worried about speed, look in to query caching, but performance shouldn't be affected in any noticeable amount.

Query caching - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html